# Gunicorn and Supervisor ERROR (no such process)

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am trying to get Supervisor to run a bash script that runs Gunicorn. I have ran the bash script alone and it works fine, however when I try to start the Supervisor program, i get the following error message:

```
guni: ERROR (no such process)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be resolved?

I have tried stopping Supervisor, restarting it, reloading it and updating it, none of which have resolved the issue.

guni.conf :: located in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/guni.conf

```
[program:guni]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/appdir/bin:/home/appdir/lib
command=/home/appdir/guni.sh
directory=/home/appdir/
user=someuser
stdout_logfile=/home/appdir/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

guni.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
LOGFILE=/home/appdir/logs/guni.log
LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
NUM_WORKERS=3
# user/group to run as
USER=someuser
GROUP=someuser
ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:8001
cd /home/appdir
source /home/appdir/bin/activate
test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
exec gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS --bind=$ADDRESS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```